# Why is jquery-ui resizable assigning width to div with "alsoResize"?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I have a set of divs like this:

```
<div id="body_container">
     <div id="top_body">
     </div>
     <div id="bottom_body">
     </div>
</div>
```

I also have this function:

```
$(function() {
   $("#top_body").resizable({handles: "s",
   alsoResize: "#bottom_body"});
});
```

The resizing works, but immediately upon starting the resize action, `#bottom_body` is assigned a fixed width (equal to it's width upon the start of the resizing action). Via css, both `#top_body` and `#bottom_body` are assigned a width of 100%. I want it to remain that way.

**Is there a way to prevent the width assignment?** I wish to allow the width to adapt to window resizes, but, with my current issue, the width assignment fixes the bottom div (but not the top one), breaking my interface.

I'm looking, ideally, for solutions that don't involve having to use JS handlers to force the width back to 100% whenever I use the resizable handle.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/3XezL/1/

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('#bottom_body').css({width: '100%'});
});
```

This will only run when the window width/height is changed, not when changing / resizing the height of your two divs, since it doesn't need to run then.